# using COUNT (CASE WHEN....) vs CASE WHEN = ...THEN COUNT . I get different results, can someone kindly explain why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i use method 1: ' COUNT (Case WHEN..) ' method it produces the output that I want, but when i use the 2nd method ' CASE WHEN .. COUNT ' method, i get a diagonal matrix of sorts which is not what I am looking for.

My steps are :

i) Created a dummy table

```
INSERT INTO job (jobid,  jobname, [priority]) 
VALUES  ('something', '1', 1), 
        ('something', '2', 2),
        ('something', '3', 3), 
        ('something', '4', 4), 
        ('something', '5', 5), 
        ('something', '6', 1), 
        ('something', '7', 1), 
        ('something', '8', 3), 
        ('something', '9', 3), 
        ('something', '10', 2);
```

ii) method 1 : COUNT (CASE WHEN....)

```
    SELECT 

COUNT(CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) as Priority1,
COUNT(CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )as Priority2,
COUNT(CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )as Priority3

FROM job
```

Result :

```
  Priority1 Priority2   Priority3
  3         2           3
```

iii) method 2 : CASE WHEN .... COUNT

```
SELECT 

CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 1 THEN COUNT(*)  END  as Priority1,
CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 2 THEN COUNT(*)  END as Priority2,
CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 3 THEN COUNT(*)  END as Priority3

FROM job

GROUP BY [Priority]
```

Result :

```
Priority1   Priority2   Priority3
3           NULL        NULL
NULL        2           NULL
NULL        NULL        3
NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Method 1 gives me the right result, but method 2's output suprised me... i was expecting the same result as method 1!

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`. Please only tag the RDBMS you're using. As for why. You have a `GROUP BY` in one statement, and not the other; it's not just the `COUNT` syntax that you have changed.

Comment: method 2 is returning 2 extra null rows bc on priority 4 and 5.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my tags, and understand the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**
The aggregate function `COUNT` is applied at the table level and `COUNT` ignored and consumed all the `NULL` values (cases where [Priority] is other than 1, 2 or 3). So, at the end you got only 1 row.

**Method 2:**
The aggregate function `COUNT` is applied to each row of the table. So, the result contains equal number of rows as the number of unique [Priority] values in the table. And result contains some `NULL` because the case condition didn't satisfied in those cases and `COUNT` return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `group by` in the second method, so you are going to get one row per value in `Priority`.

So you sort of want:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 1 THEN COUNT(*)  END  as Priority1,
       CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 2 THEN COUNT(*)  END as Priority2,
       CASE  WHEN  [Priority] = 3 THEN COUNT(*)  END as Priority3
FROM job;
```

But this won't work.  Because `[Priority]` is not aggregated.

Hmmm, you are basically back to your first method, where the condition is in the argument to the aggregation function  Your expectation is wrong.  Use the first method (although I personally prefer using `SUM()` to `COUNT()`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why do you prefer SUM() to COUNT()?

Comment: @DCH . . . Because `COUNT(2)` = `COUNT(1)`, and I've seen people put pretty funky things in the `THEN` clause.